# Find regular expression for a given language $L=\{0^{n}1^{m}\,\,\,|\,\,\,n+m(mod3)\neq0\}$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

**Question.**

> Write a regular expression for the language:
> $L=\{0^{n}1^{m}\,\,\,|\,\,\,n+m(mod3)\neq0\}$

**Attempt.**

> $r=(000)^* (0(ε+0+1+011)+1(ε+1)) (111)^*$

Is my regular expression correct? If so, is there a shorter expression ?

Comment: What makes a regular expression shorter than another?

Comment: You can always verify your answers using $\texttt{JFlap}.$ The only way to get a shorter expression is to simplify it using known properties. I don't see the point of doing it here.

Comment: @roro verify by converting the automata to RE?

Comment: @DanielG For example. You can also do RE $\to \text{ NFA}$  and check if it recognizes the language $\mathcal L = \{0^n1^m \, | \, n + m \, (\text{mod } 3) \, \neq 0\}$.

Comment: @roro nice! good to know, thanks!